# Unable to get the user public details when using through GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My required functionality is to search for users in Facebook that closely match my search criteria. As a first step, I am trying to get the general details of the users. Suppose say when I search for users whose name as "John Smith", I am getting a list of users.I am able to fetch very few details like id & name only. Say one "John Smith" id is 123456789. I could not get his details of "Relationship status","location", etc through graph api.

[Through Graph API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5xVb.jpg)

However if I search for the person using  the url "https://fb.com/123456789" I can see the general details like relationship_status, location, hometown..etc.

My general understanding is that if can see the details of a person when entering through url, I should also able to get his details when using graph-api. But it is not happening. Am I missing something? Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your general understanding is simply wrong. That you can see something publicly on facebook.com, does not mean the same information is freely available via API. The user would have to login to your app and grant it permissions to access this kind of data first, before your app can access it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Ok now I understood the problem. But by using API, is there any way that we can get the same details that we see publicly on facebook.com ?

Comment: everything you can get is in the api reference

Comment: _“But by using API, is there any way that we can get the same details that we see publicly on facebook.com ?”_ - not without each and every single user granting your app permission first.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like I need to rely on other rough ways (not API)  to get the details from facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general understanding is simply wrong. That you can see something publicly on facebook.com, does not mean the same information is freely available via API. The user would have to login to your app and grant it permissions to access this kind of data first, before your app can access it. – CBroe 1 hour ago